# Python Selenium Webdriver element found but can not click on it

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, checkbox, webdriver

Goal is to click on a checkbox on login page. 
I find the element by XPATH, but can't click on it.

```
>>> elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][@name='conditions']")
>>> elem.is_displayed()
False
>>> elem.is_enabled()
True
>>> elem.get_attribute('outerHTML')
u'<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="conditions">'
```

When I try `elem.click()`, exception occurs: 
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible` but element is clearly visible, since the page is loaded and I work from terminal.

Other error when I use different selector is: 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/section/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/p[1]/label/input').click()`

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="conditions"> is not clickable at point (51, 549). Other element would receive the click: <span class="custom-control-description font-weight-regular">...</span>`

I tried with injecting JavaScript but didn't work. 
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';",elem)`

Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: try to explicit wait for the visibility of element then click on it.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code trials when you try :

```
elem.click()
```

You are seeing :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Which means the desired element is still not visible in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Even before trying to click when you are try :

```
elem.is_displayed()
```

You are seeing :

```
False
```

But when you try :

```
elem.is_enabled()
```

You are seeing :

```
True
```

So combining all these observations it can be either of the situations :

- Element is **present** in the *DOM* but still not visible/interactable. In this case you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and then invoke `click()` as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='conditions']"))).click()
  ```
- Element is **present** in the *DOM* but not within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). In this case you need to invoke `execute_script()` to bring the element within the *Viewport* and then invoke `click()` as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='conditions']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)
  elem.click()
  ```
- There is a possibility that the *Locator Strategy* you have adapted is not unique and identifies multiple *WebElements* and the first element to be identified may be hidden. In this case `is_displayed()` will always return **False** and you have to construct a unique *Locator Strategy* which identifies the intended element uniquely.
- There is a possibility that the *style* attribute of the element is set to **display: none;** and in that case you have to use `execute_script()` method as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='conditions']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", elem)
  elem.click()
  ```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB great answer, I tried and double checked all of it, but always get the error: `Element ... is not clickable at point ...`

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="conditions"> is not clickable at point (51, 286). Other element would receive the click: <span class="custom-control-description font-weight-regular">...</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPATH :- `//input[@type='checkbox'and @name='conditions']`

For below error:-  Use wait before click event

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (51, 549). Other element would receive the click: ...